# LibGDX game freezes (because of a mulithreading issue?)

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, libgdx

After playing my libgdx-game for some time, it just freezes. the game loop is not being executed anymore and it does not react to any input; the game can just be killed.

Logcat says this:
[image: debug output]

The memory graph shows:
[image: memory graph]
(The freeze starts at about 8m30s. Before this time the game is running normally.)

The question: What is happing here? What do I have to do to avoid this game crash?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post more logcat? It's hard do gather any information as to what is causing the problem just by looking at it saying it's suspending all threads.

This usually happens when you run out of memory. Do you have peices of code which load stuff into memory? You may want to take a look at that. Just a possibility, but maybe you are running out of memory. I know what the memory graph shows, but I had a similar problem and I fixed it by optimizing some asset loading.

(you may want to use asset manager to handle memory optimization)

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

If that is not the case, please post some code. (or more logcat)